Prove or disprove bijective and continuous function preserves adherent and boundary point
Problem: Let $f:X\to Y$ be continuous and bijective, for all $S\subset X$. Prove or disprove (a) $f$ preserves adherent point, ie $f(\bar{S})\subset\overline{f(S)}$; (b) $f$ preserve boundary point, ie $f(\partial S)\subset\partial (f(S))$.
There is a similar question for general continuous function (question b). However, I am wondering if the statement is true if the function is bijective.
Here is my attempt:
(b). True, $\forall y\in f(\partial S),\exists x\in\partial S$ such that $f(x)=y\implies x\in\bar{S}\cap\overline{X\backslash S}\implies f(x)\in f(\bar{S})\cap f(\overline{X\backslash S})\implies y\in\overline{f(S)}\cap\overline{f(X\backslash S)}\implies y\in\partial(f(S))$, so proven.
I am not sure if my answers are rigorous.
Thanks in advance!

This question has been mis-edited: There is an accepted answer, which references some "(a)" and "(b)" parts that are no longer there?

The intuition (and first thing you should prove) is that a continuous bijective function should map open sets to open sets.  A continuous function by definition maps "near" things to near things so sets can be open but if it isn't bijective you can "fold" an open set onto itself and the result has an "edge" but that's avoided if it's bijective.  ... so if images of open sets are open sets this will follow immediately be definitions.

It is not a good idea to edit the Question as severely as you have after receiving an Answer of substance, as in this case.  In particular you removed the designations of (a) and (b) parts of the exercise, causing a conflict with the notation in the Answer.  Providing the source of the exercise would have been useful as an edit.

sorry about mis-editing, I will recover the previous version

(a) is true but you didn't prove it. $f(B(x,r))∩f(S)≠∅⟹B(y,r′)∩f(S)≠∅$
should be $[∀r>0,f(B(x,r))∩f(S)≠∅]⟹[∀r′>0,B(y,r′)∩f(S)≠∅]$, and requires a justification, using the continuity of $f$. Moreover, you are assuming tacitely that $X,Y$ are metric spaces, which, incidentally, is not necessary: they could as well be any topological spaces (link found using Approach$0$).
(b) is also true (would be false if $f$ was not injective, link found using again Approach$0$). Your last implication should be justified explicitely by $f(X\setminus S)\subseteq Y\setminus f(S)$, using the injectivity of $f$.
Note that the surjectivity of $f$ is used nowhere.

For (b), you may have missed that $f$ is bijective, so for $y\in f(X\backslash S),\exists x\in X\backslash S,$ such that $f(x)=y$. Moreover, $x\in X\backslash S\implies x\in X \cap x\notin S\implies f(x)\in f(X)\cap f(x)\notin f(S)$ (because $f$ is injective), so $y\in Y\backslash f(S)$. So in this case is my proof still rigorous. Thanks!

Sorry, you are right! I just  fixed my answer. However, the first formulas in your comment don't need bijectivity. If $y∈f(X\setminus S)$ then (by definition) $∃x∈X\setminus S$
such that $f(x)=y$.
